# Merge one row to all in a single data step

Tags: sas

Two data sets:

1. The first data set has many observations:

   ```
   data ds1;
     do var1=1 to 3;
       output;
     end;
   run;
   ```
2. The second data set has 1 observation:

   ```
   data ds2;
     var2=1;
   run;
   ```

The number of variables in each data set is irrelevant.

I want to merge the single observation in DS2 to all observations in DS1 to get:

Data set DS3:

```
VAR1 VAR2
1    1
2    1
3    1
```

I know I can do this using a PROC SQL step:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table ds3 as
  select a.*, b.*
  from ds1 as a, ds2 as b;
quit;
```

Is it possible to preform this with a **single** data step?

Comment: Your data sample is too small to completely understand what you want. Are you saying you will have a data set with many values in VAR1 and a data set with 1 value in VAR2 and you want to MERGE them into one data set, using a DATA STEP? So that your single variable VAR2 is in every observation in the MERGED data set?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If VAR2 is always going to be 1, then this would work:

```
ds3;
   retain var2 1;
   do var1 = 1 to 3;
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Similarly, if DS1 and DS2 already exist and DS2 has only one observation as in your example, then this should work:

```
ds3;
   set ds1;
   if _n_ eq 1 then do;
      set ds2;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: the second solution is what I was looking for. Thanks.